# Replace a string within double quotes in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to replace some text in a csv file. I want to replace comma's only if they are within double quotes. How would I do this in Powershell?

```
Example input:
ID, City, State
1,"Cape, Town",Tx
2,Sarasota,Fl
3,"Long, Beach",Ca

Example output:
ID, Name, Title
1,"Cape Town",Tx
2,Sarasota,Fl
3,"Long Beach",Ca
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question fully, I think you're worried about your CSV structure, as opposed to the possibilities of having Cities without quotes, in which the comma should not be removed? Doesn't make much sense to me, since that would probably be breaking things. Anyway...

```
$x = Import-CSV ex.csv
$x |% {$_.City = $_.City.Replace(',','')}
$x | Export-CSV out.csv
```

This probably will work for you.

Comment: My example is a simplified example. The column that could have quotes may not always be apparent. However, the main objective is to replace only commas within quoted strings. This would preserve CSV format for import.

Comment: Yeah, you can't replace any commas other than those within quotes. :) It's not possible via the replace method, since when you Import-Csv it is translated into a Powershell object table. So this solution will always work for you, you just need to add additional statements for more columns, and rename as needed.

Comment: If you don't have/want a structured file, you can also use something like this `Import-csv ex.csv | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'` to make an array of headers, and loop through it with the above.

Comment: Easier than using `Get-Member` and `Select -Expand` is to use the hidden PSObject property. So `$CSV = Import-Csv ex.csv;$CSV[0].PSObject.Properties.Name` would get you a listing of the header columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the delimiter, replace and rechange delimiter :

```
(import-csv "c:\temp\file1.csv" | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoType ).Replace(',', '').Replace(';', ',') | out-file "c:\temp\file1.csv"
```